# get value from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am building a website of yellopages in which I want to upload and display images on some pages.

First, I insert the image name in to the database while uploading. I want to get the image name on the parent page.

**addproduct.php**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadform" id="uploadform">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
     <td width="42%" align="right">Product Title </td>
     <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
     <td width="118" height="118" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><iframe src="" id="fileframe" name="fileframe" width="118" height="118" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td onclick="whatever();">value</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><label>
      <input name="thefile" type="file" id="thefile" />
     <a href="#" class="uploadfile">upload</a></label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Product Description </td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3"></td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><label>
       <input name="web" type="submit" id="web" value="Continue" />
     </label></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Javascript in this page**

```
function whatever() {
   mmspobj=document.getElementId("fileframe");
   // if (mmspobj.tagName=='iframe'){
   //alert("hi");
   //mmsiobj=window.frames[fileframe].document.getElementId('fileframe').value;
   alert(mmspobj);
   //}
}
```

**uploader.js**

```
function init() {
   fileUploadEvents();
}

function fileUploadEvents() {
   var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   if (links) {  
      for (var x=0; x<links.length; ++x) {
         if (links[x].className == "uploadfile")
         links[x].onclick = uploadFile;
      }
   }
}

function uploadFile() {
   var uploadForm = document.getElementById("uploadform");

   if (uploadForm) {
      uploadForm.target="fileframe";
      uploadForm.action="upload.php";
   }

   uploadForm.submit();
}
```

How can I get the image name in `addproduct.php`?

Comment: Can you create a test case (<50 LOC)?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to have the iframe call a JavaScript function in the parent, rather than have the parent window try to read the name from the iframe.